# Requiring external js file for mocha testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, bdd, mocha.js

So I'm playing around with BDD and mocha with my express.js project. I'm just getting started so here is what I have as my first test case:

```
should = require "should"
require "../lib/models/skill.js"


describe 'Skill', ->
    describe '#constructor()', ->
        it 'should return an instance of class skill', ->
            testSkill = new Skill "iOS", "4 years", 100
            testSkill.constructor.name.should.equal 'Skill'
```

(also this coffeescript generates some odd looking js since it inserts returns to last statement.. is this the correct way to setup a test with coffeescript?)

Now when I run mocha I get this error:

```
 1) Skill #constructor() should return an instance of class skill:
     ReferenceError: Skill is not defined
```

Which I assume means skill.js was not imported correctly. My skill class is very simple at this point, just a constructor:

```
class Skill
    constructor: (@name,@years,@width) ->
```

How do I import my models so my mocha test can access them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to export your Skill class like this:

```
class Skill
    constructor: (@name,@years,@width) ->

module.exports = Skill
```

And assign it to variable in your test:

```
should = require "should"
Skill = require "../lib/models/skill.js"


describe 'Skill', ->
    describe '#constructor()', ->
        it 'should return an instance of class skill', ->
            testSkill = new Skill "iOS", "4 years", 100
            testSkill.constructor.name.should.equal 'Skill'
```

Answer (score 0):

if skill.js is in the same path of your test code, try this.

```
require "./skill.js"
```