# JavaScript test (mocha) with 'import' js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, require, mocha.js

I understand `module.export` and `require` mannner:

[Requiring external js file for mocha testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258806/requiring-external-js-file-for-mocha-testing)

Although it's pretty usable as long as it's a module, I feel this manner is inconvenient since what I intends to do now is to test a code in a file.

For instance, I have a code in a file:

**app.js**

```
'use strict';
console.log('app.js is running');
var INFINITY = 'INFINITY';
```

and now, I want to test this code in a file:

**test.js**

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;

require('./app.js');


    describe('INFINITY', function()
    {
        it('INFINITY === "INFINITY"',
            function()
            {
                expect(INFINITY)
                    .to.equal('INFINITY');
            });
    });
```

The test code executes `app.js`, so the output is;

`app.js is running`

then

`ReferenceError: INFINITY is not defined`

This is not what I expected.

I do not want to use `module.export` and to write like

`var app = require('./app.js');`

and

`app.INFINITY` and `app.anyOtherValue` for every line in the test code.

There must be a smart way. Could you tell me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

UPDATE: FINAL ANSWER:

My previous answer is invalid since `eval(code);` is not useful for variables.

Fortunately, `node` has a strong method - `vm`

http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html

However, according to the doc,

> The vm module has many known issues and edge cases. If you run into
> issues or unexpected behavior, please consult the open issues on
> GitHub. Some of the biggest problems are described below.

so, although this works on the surface, extra care needed for such an purpose like testing...

```
var expect = require('chai')
    .expect;

var fs = require('fs');
var vm = require('vm');
var path = './app.js';

var code = fs.readFileSync(path);
vm.runInThisContext(code);

describe('SpaceTime', function()
{
    describe('brabra', function()
    {
        it('MEMORY === "MEMORY"',
            function()
            {
                expect(MEMORY)
                    .to.equal('MEMORY');
            })
    });

});
```

**AFTER ALL;
The best way I found in this case is
to write the test mocha code in the same file.**

Answer (score 6):

I usually include a `_test` object containing references to all my "private" internal variables and functions and expose it on exports. In your case:

**./app.js**

```
var INFINITY = 'infinity';

function foo() {
    return 'bar';
}

exports._test = {
    INFINITY: INFINITY,
    foo: foo
}
```

**./test/app-test.js**

```js
var app = require('../app.js')
/* ... */
it('should equal bar', function() {
    expect(app._test.foo()).to.equal('bar');
});
it('should equal infinity', function() {
    expect(app._test.INFINITY).to.equal('infinity');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand your answer. I would search a solution to test without modifications to the testing code, as well as without a prefix object to refer it.

Comment: thanks. I sort of resolving this issue, and when done, I will post the solution, so stay tuned!

Comment: I found the solution, check my answer.