# Cutting out code from a js file with gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, mocha.js

To be able to test `app.js` with gulp-mocha by requiring it, I add the last 3 lines to the file:

```
function foo(){
  return 'foobar';
}

//For the sake of testing
if(typeof exports !== 'undefined'){
  exports.foo = foo;
}
```

I don't want this code to appear in the browser, it just exists for testing purposes.
Is there a way to cut it out with gulp while exporting the file to the `build` directory? Something like `gulp-html-replace` but for javascript?

Comment: Could you not do the reverse, and use Gulp to add the lines of text to your code when testing?

Comment: Try to use node's `vm` module, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21424044/1115187