# (Beginner) Mocha : How to test dependent classes?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Mocha and try to get arount with testing my classes.
I have read several posts, including these two :

- [JavaScript test (mocha) with 'import' js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421701/javascript-test-mocha-with-import-js-file)
- [Requiring external js file for mocha testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258806/requiring-external-js-file-for-mocha-testing)

But I can't figure out how to make it works for me :-/

I have two classes :

**Fichier.js**

```
function Fichier(path){

    this.local_path = path;
    this.local_data = NaN;
}
module.exports = Fichier
```

**Arbre.js**

```
function Arbre(chemin)
{
    this.path       = chemin ; 
    this.fichier    = new Fichier(this.path);
    this.noeuds = [];
    this.fichier.lecture(this.make_structure, [this]);    
}
```

**Arbre-spec.js**

```
'use strict';

var expect  = require('chai').expect    ;
var Fichier = require('./Fichier.js')     ;

describe('Arbre', function() {  

            it('should exist', function() 
                                {
                                    var Fichier = require('./Fichier.js')   ;
                                    var Arbre   = require('./Arbre.js'  )   ;
                                    expect(Arbre).to.not.be.undefined       ;
                                });
});
```

The issue is that my class "Arbre" is depending on the class "Fichier", which is not loaded, as the output of the test tells me :

```
$ mocha arbre-spec.js


  Arbre
hello
    1) should exist


  0 passing (9ms)
  1 failing

  1) Arbre should exist:
     ReferenceError: Fichier is not defined
      at new Arbre (arbre.js:29:22)
      at Object.<anonymous> (arbre.js:111:16)
      at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
      at Context.<anonymous> (arbre-spec.js:13:49)
```

How should I import "Fichier" to make the test run ?

**EDIT**

Following the comment I added : require in Arbre.js :

```
require ("./Fichier.js")
require ("./Noeud.js")
require ("./Feuille.js")
```

I still have the error :

```
//Arbre-spec.js
'use strict';

var expect  = require('chai').expect    ;

describe('Arbre', function() 
                    {   
                        it('should exist', function() 
                                            {
                                                var Arbre   = require('./Arbre.js'  )   ;                        
                                                expect(Arbre).to.not.be.undefined       ;
                                            });
                        it('', function() 
                                            {
                                                var Arbre   = require('./Arbre.js'  )   ;                                                                       
                                                console.log(Arbre)
                                                expect(new Arbre("")).to.not.be.undefined       ;
                                            });
});
```

gives me a mistake inside the Arbre.js functions :

```
$ mocha Arbre-spec.js


  Arbre
    ✓ should exist
[Function: Arbre]
    1)


  1 passing (18ms)
  1 failing

  1) Arbre :
     ReferenceError: Fichier is not defined
      at new Arbre (Arbre.js:27:22)
      at Context.<anonymous> (Arbre-spec.js:17:47)
```

Having **Arbre.js** :

```
require ("./Fichier.js")
require ("./Noeud.js")
require ("./Feuille.js")
function Arbre(chemin)
{
    this.path       = chemin ; 
    this.fichier    = new Fichier(this.path);
    this.noeuds     = [];
    this.fichier.lecture(this.make_structure, [this]);


}
```

Comment: You need to require the `Fichier` class in the file containing the `Arbre` class. If you look at your stack trace, you'll see that the error has occurred in your arbre.js` file and not in the spec file.

Comment: I changed the question accordingly, but without better results :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the require call for it to work.

In `Arbre.js` for example

```
var Fichier = require ("./Fichier.js");
var Noeud = require ("./Noeud.js");
var Feuille = require ("./Feuille.js");

function Arbre(chemin)
{
    this.path       = chemin ; 
    this.fichier    = new Fichier(this.path);
    this.noeuds     = [];
    this.fichier.lecture(this.make_structure, [this]);


}
```

You can think of `modules.exports` as an unnamed value (the value can be a function as in `Fichier.js` or something else) and by assigning it to a variable when using `require` you give it a name! Otherwise, the program will crash complaining that you are referring to something that doesn't exist in the current scope.

Comment: This should fix your problem. For context, you should read more about Common.js / Node.js module loading. It's likely not quite the same as other languages you may have worked with.

Comment: how do I come back to "normal" code after having added all these "require" : my simple http server doesn't recognise them (even if the tests pass)

Comment: If your javascript is loaded in a browser page, it is not natively supported to use require, the current written form is the one used in Node.js. There are tools out there that can compile this into js readable by a browser. You could use webpack (webpack.github.io).